# AJAX calls - dynamic JSON db array - to hide HTML elements - with CSS visibility property

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, ajax

I'm a super excited novice, stuck on this; can't find this anywhere, please help:

How to get the var `dotContainer` to be all of the ids from the JSON DB, as to make all the matching HTML id elements invisible using the CSS “dot-hide” property (appose to just this one “n788” id specified with getElementById).

So the JSON database which updates dynamically with new id values (like n790 or n786) will asynchronously hide the matching HTML id element dots with the CSS “dot-hide".

**JavaScript**

```js
var dotContainer = document.getElementById("n788"); //THIS TO CONTAIN ALL ID VALUES FROM THE JSON DB
    var dataRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    dataRequest.open('get', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sicronerver/sicronerve/master/dbn.json');
    dataRequest.onload = function() {
        var ourData = JSON.parse(dataRequest.responseText);
        //setInterval(function(){ 
            renderdata(ourData);
        //}, 1000);      
    };
dataRequest.send(); {
    }
function renderdata(dataobjectarray) {
        var texString = ""
        for (i = 0; i < dataobjectarray.length; i++) {
            texString += dataobjectarray[i].id + ",";
        }
  dotContainer.insertAdjacentText('afterEnd', texString); //REFERENCE OF JSON ID VALUES TO HIDE HTML ID ELEMENTS
  dotContainer.classList.add("dot-hide");
}
```

**JSON**

```
[{"id":"n787"},{"id":"n788"},{"id":"n789"}]
```

**HTML**

```html
<div class="grid">
  <a id = "n786" class = "dot" href="#786"></a>  
  <a id = "n787" class = "dot" href="#787"></a>  
  <a id = "n788" class = "dot" href="#788"></a>  
  <a id = "n789" class = "dot" href="#789"></a>
  <a id = "n790" class = "dot" href="#790"></a>
```

**CSS**

```css
.dot-hide {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(.75);
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(16, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(9, 1fr);
}

.dot {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #777777;
}

.dot:hover {
  background-color: rgb(60, 255, 0);
  opacity: 50%;
}

.dot:active {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  opacity: 50%;
}

#n786 {
  position: relative;
  grid-column: 3 / span 2;
  grid-row: 6 / span 2;
}

#n787 {
  position: relative;
  grid-column: 6 / span 2;
  grid-row: 6 / span 2;
}

#n788 {
  position: relative;
  grid-column: 9 / span 2;
  grid-row: 6 / span 2;
}

#n789 {
  position: relative;
  grid-column: 12 / span 2;
  grid-row: 6 / span 2;
}

#n790 {
  position: relative;
  grid-column: 15 / span 2;
  grid-row: 6 / span 2;
}
```

I made a pen here: https://codepen.io/andijonson/pen/gOpEmEQ

Many thanks, Andi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add and remove css.

Sample:

```
var dotContainer = document.getElementById("n788"); //THIS TO CONTAIN ALL ID VALUES FROM THE JSON DB
var dataRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
dataRequest.open(
  "get",
  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sicronerver/sicronerve/master/dbn.json"
);
dataRequest.onload = function() {
  var ourData = JSON.parse(dataRequest.responseText);
  //setInterval(function(){
  renderdata(ourData);
  //}, 1000);
};
dataRequest.send();

function renderdata(dataobjectarray) {
  document.querySelectorAll("div a").forEach(x => {
    x.className = "dot";
  });
  var texString = "";
  for (i = 0; i < dataobjectarray.length; i++) {
    texString += dataobjectarray[i].id + ",";
  }
  dotContainer.insertAdjacentText("afterEnd", texString);
}
```

Demo:

```js
window.onload = () => {
  function fetchData() {
    fetch(
      "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sicronerver/sicronerve/master/dbn.json"
    )
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(renderdata);
  }
  function renderdata(data) {
    document.querySelectorAll("div a").forEach(x => {
      x.classList.remove("hide");
    });
    data.forEach(item => {
      const elm = document.getElementById(item.id);
      elm.classList.add("hide");
    });
  }
  function start() {
    setInterval(fetchData, 2000);
  }
  start();
};
```

```css
.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(16, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(9, 1fr);
}

.dot {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #777777;
}
  
.dot:hover {
  background-color: rgb(60, 255, 0);
  opacity: 50%;
}
  
.dot:active {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  opacity: 50%;
}

#n786 {
  position: relative;
  grid-column: 3 / span 2;
  grid-row: 6 / span 2;
}

#n787 {
  position: relative;
  grid-column: 6 / span 2;
  grid-row: 6 / span 2;
}

#n788 {
  position: relative;
  grid-column: 9 / span 2;
  grid-row: 6 / span 2;
}

#n789 {
  position: relative;
  grid-column: 12 / span 2;
  grid-row: 6 / span 2;
}

#n790 {
  position: relative;
  grid-column: 15 / span 2;
  grid-row: 6 / span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <a id="n786" class="dot" href="#"></a>
    <a id="n787" class="dot" href="#"></a>
    <a id="n788" class="dot" href="#"></a>
    <a id="n789" class="dot" href="#"></a>
    <a id="n790" class="dot" href="#"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, wow thank you so much ! is there a simple way for this to run asynchronously – so that when the json database changes, the relevant dot will be made hidden without having to refresh the page. I tried `setInterval` but it only writes what has already been loaded to the console. Many thanks, Andi

Comment: I ticked your very good answer green, thank you! if you have an answer on the asynchronous aspect I'd be very grateful, since I know it is a separate question! Many thanks Andi

Comment: when u want to fetch ?? some interval ??

Comment: I thought every one second?

Comment: unless there is another way to check when database has updated and so change asynchronously without page refresh. PS I'm a newbie and still learning =) so thank you very much!

Comment: I did little bit clean up. please check. :-)

Comment: ENjoy!! Stay home!Stay safe

Comment: use `fetch` to get data

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! Super hitech!! `fetch` works really well asynchronously)) how fast can I take that 2000? safe to go 1000? or even 100?

Comment: 2000 is 2 secs, it depends on ue need, 1 secs will be ok

Comment: Perfect! @xdeepakv

Comment: and thank you so much again! I learned something fantastic this week from a king of code! =) Stay safe too and peace to you!

Comment: Hi @xdeepakv – I was just playing around with this again – is there a way to load this so the three dots are already removed from the start? And then once loaded it will check for database updates every 2 seconds? (As to not reveal all the dots at the start, and only show the relevant dots, so the dots will only load once the database is accessed.) Many thanks Andi